# symfony insert multiple rows insted of one

Tags: php, mysql, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a wired situation here. On persisting symfony inserts multiple records instead of one. I can't find any problem with my code and I am not sure how to debug this error because it seems all fine.

Logic behind application is that user can select two bus station and create a route. Also he needs to define price and group (minimum and maximum people). Additionally, user needs to select bus vehicles that will drive this particular route

Does someone knows where is the problem?

Here is the output of entity when form is submitted

```
StationStandardPrice {#553 ▼
  -id: null
  -company: Company {#549 ▶}
  -busVehicleGroupSize: BusVehicleGroupSize {#1233 ▶}
  -departureStation: Stations {#1247 ▶}
  -destinationStation: Stations {#1236 ▶}
  -currency: Currencies {#1015 ▶ …2}
  -price: 99.0
  -busVehicles: ArrayCollection {#554 ▼
    -elements: array:2 [▼
      0 => BusVehicle {#1023 ▶}
      1 => BusVehicle {#1208 ▶}
    ]
  }
}
```

This is entity of route (shorted version)

```
/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Company
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */

    private $company;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\BusVehicleGroupSize
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BusVehicleGroupSize")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bus_vehicle_group_size_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $busVehicleGroupSize;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Stations
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Stations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="departure_station_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $departureStation;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Stations
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Stations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="destination_station_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $destinationStation;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Currencies
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Currencies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="currency_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */

    private $currency;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=false)
     */

    private $price;

    /**
     *  Many groups can have many bus vehicles
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BusVehicle", inversedBy="busVehicleGroup")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="standard_station_price_bus_groups",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="station_standard_price_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="bus_vehicle_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     **/

    private $busVehicles;

  /**
 * Add bus vehicle
 * @param BusVehicle $busVehicles
 */
public function addBusVehicles(BusVehicle $busVehicles)
{
    if ($this->busVehicles->contains($busVehicles)) {
        return;
    }
    $this->busVehicles->add($busVehicles);
    $busVehicles->addBusVehicleGroup($this);
}



  /**
     * Remove bus vehicle
     * @param BusVehicle $busVehicles
     */
public function removeBusVehicles(BusVehicle $busVehicles)
{
    if (!$this->busVehicles->contains($busVehicles)) {
        return;
    }
    $this->busVehicles->remove($busVehicles);
    $busVehicles->removeBusVehicleGroup($this);
}
```

Controller:

```
/**
     * Creates a new stationStandardPrice entity.
     * @Template
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $stationStandardPrice = new Stationstandardprice();
        $form = $this->createForm(StationStandardPriceType::class, $stationStandardPrice, array(
                'user' => $this->getUser()
            )
        );
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            dump($stationStandardPrice);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($stationStandardPrice);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'admin.stationstandardprice.created');
            //return $this->redirectToRoute('stationstandardprice_show', array('id' => $stationStandardPrice->getId()));
        }

        return [
            'stationStandardPrice' => $stationStandardPrice,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ];
    }
```

Database output:

[image: After persisting values]

Many to Many table status:

[image: Many to many table output]

**EDIT 1: Added twig**

```
{% extends 'AdminBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <link href="{{ asset('resources/public/css/datatables.min.css', 'busrent_admin') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="{{ asset('resources/public/css/smart_wizard.min.css', 'busrent_admin') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="{{ asset('resources/public/css/smart_wizard_theme_dots.min.css', 'busrent_admin') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
{% endblock %}
{% block title %} {{ 'admin.stationstandardprice.new.title'|trans }} {% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <h2>{{ 'admin.stationstandardprice.new.title'|trans }}</h2>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path('dashboard') }}">{{ 'admin.dashboard.index.title'|trans }}  </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path('stationstandardprice_index') }}">{{ 'admin.stationstandardprice.index.title'|trans }}  </a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <strong>{{ 'admin.stationstandardprice.new.title'|trans }}</strong>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">

    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title">
                        <h5>{{ 'admin.stationstandardprice.new.title'|trans }}</h5>
                        <div class="ibox-tools">
                            <a class="collapse-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                            </a>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">

                                {{ form_start(form) }}

                                <div id="smartwizard">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#step-1">Step Title<br/>
                                                <small>Step description</small>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#step-2">Step Title<br/>
                                                <small>Step description</small>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#step-3">Step Title<br/>
                                                <small>Step description</small>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>

                                    <div>
                                        <div id="step-1" class="">
                                            {{ form_row(form.departureStation) }}
                                            {{ form_row(form.destinationStation) }}
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="step-2" class="">
                                            {{ form_row(form.busVehicleGroupSize) }}
                                            {{ form_row(form.price) }}
                                            {{ form_row(form.currency) }}
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="step-3" class="">
                                            {% if app.user.company is not null %}
                                                <div class="ibox-content">

                                                    <table id="busVehicleTable" class="table table-striped">
                                                        <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>{{ 'admin.busvehicle.form.licencePlate'|trans }}</th>
                                                            <th>{{ 'admin.busvehicle.form.chassisNumber'|trans }}</th>
                                                            <th>{{ 'admin.busvehicle.form.passengerSeatsNumber'|trans }}</th>
                                                            <th>{{ 'admin.busvehicle.form.busType'|trans }}</th>
                                                            <th>{{ 'admin.busvehicle.form.emissionClass'|trans }}</th>
                                                            <th>{{ 'admin.busvehicle.form.fullDayPrice'|trans }}</th>
                                                            <th>{{ 'admin.busvehicle.form.halfDayPrice'|trans }}</th>
                                                            <th>{{ 'admin.busvehicle.form.pricePerKm'|trans }}</th>
                                                            <th>{{ 'admin.busvehicle.form.amenities'|trans }}</th>
                                                            <th>{{ 'actions'|trans }}</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                        {% set inc = 0 %}
                                                        {% for busVehicle in app.user.company.busVehicle %}

                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>{{ busVehicle.licencePlate }}</td>
                                                                <td>{{ busVehicle.chassisNumber }}</td>
                                                                <td>{{ busVehicle.passengerSeatsNumber }}</td>
                                                                <td>{{ busVehicle.busType.type }}</td>
                                                                <td>{{ busVehicle.emissionClass.name }}</td>

                                                                <td>{{ busVehicle.fullDayPrice }}</td>
                                                                <td>{{ busVehicle.halfDayPrice }}</td>
                                                                <td>{{ busVehicle.pricePerKm }}</td>

                                                                <td>
                                                                    <i style="cursor: pointer;" class="fa fa-search"
                                                                       aria-hidden="true"
                                                                       data-toggle="collapse"
                                                                       data-target="#amenities{{ inc }}"></i>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <div id="addBusVehicleDiv{{ busVehicle.id }}">
                                                                        <button data-id="{{ busVehicle.id }}" href="#"
                                                                                class="addBusVehicle btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                                                            <span class="bold"> Add bus vehicle</span>
                                                                        </button>

                                                                    </div>

                                                                    <div id="removeBusVehicleDiv{{ busVehicle.id }}"
                                                                         style="display: none;">
                                                                        <div id="removeBusVehicleDiv{{ busVehicle.id }}">
                                                                            <button data-id="{{ busVehicle.id }}"
                                                                                    href="#"
                                                                                    class="removeBusVehicle btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                                                                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                                                                <span class="bold"> Remove bus vehicle</span>
                                                                            </button>

                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>

                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr id="amenities{{ inc }}" class="collapse">
                                                                <td>
                                                                    >{{ 'admin.busvehicle.form.amenities'|trans }}:
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <p>
                                                                            {% for busAmenity in  busVehicle.busVehiclesAmenities %}
                                                                                {% if loop.last %}
                                                                                    {{ busAmenity.name }}
                                                                                {% else %}
                                                                                    {{ busAmenity.name }},
                                                                                {% endif %}

                                                                            {% endfor %}
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                            {% set inc = inc + 1 %}
                                                        {% endfor %}
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>

                                                </div>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                {{ form_end(form) }}


                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('resources/public/js/jquery.smartWizard.min.js', 'busrent_admin') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('resources/public/js/busVehicleGroup.js', 'busrent_admin') }}"></script>



{% endblock %}
```

JS:

```
  // Smart Wizard
    $('#smartwizard').smartWizard({
        selected: 0,  // Initial selected step, 0 = first step
        keyNavigation:true, // Enable/Disable keyboard navigation(left and right keys are used if enabled)
        autoAdjustHeight:true, // Automatically adjust content height
        cycleSteps: false, // Allows to cycle the navigation of steps
        backButtonSupport: true, // Enable the back button support
        showStepURLhash: true,
        useURLhash: true, // Enable selection of the step based on url hash
        lang: {  // Language variables
            next: 'Next',
            previous: 'Previous'
        },
        toolbarSettings: {
            toolbarPosition: 'bottom', // none, top, bottom, both
            toolbarButtonPosition: 'right', // left, right
            showNextButton: true, // show/hide a Next button
            showPreviousButton: true, // show/hide a Previous button
            toolbarExtraButtons: [
                $('<button disabled id="finishForm" type="submit"></button>').text('Finish')
                    .addClass('btn btn-info')

            ]
        },
        anchorSettings: {
            anchorClickable: false, // Enable/Disable anchor navigation
            enableAllAnchors: false, // Activates all anchors clickable all times
            markDoneStep: true, // add done css
            enableAnchorOnDoneStep: true // Enable/Disable the done steps navigation
        },
        contentURL: null, // content url, Enables Ajax content loading. can set as data data-content-url on anchor
        disabledSteps: [],    // Array Steps disabled
        errorSteps: [],    // Highlight step with errors
        theme: 'dots',
        transitionEffect: 'fade', // Effect on navigation, none/slide/fade
        transitionSpeed: '400'
    });

    $("#smartwizard").on("showStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection) {
        if (stepNumber == 2){
            $('#finishForm').attr("disabled", false);
        }
        else{
            $('#finishForm').attr("disabled", true);
        }

    });
```

Comment: How the client for this looking?

Comment: @Webbanditten you mean how client form is looking ?

Comment: Yes, I do what does your HTML/Javascript/CSS Look like

Comment: @Webbanditten I updated my post. Thank you for your help

Comment: I think it might be caused by your addBusVehicles code. You are adding a BusVehicle to the BusVehicleGroup with this line:  $this->busVehicles->add($busVehicles);. Symfony already creates a connection between the BusVehicleGroup and the BusVehicle since you have your tables joined with a ManyToMany. Then, you are adding an additional connection with line: $busVehicles->addBusVehicleGroup($this);.

Comment: @mcriecken I removed that line and problem is still there. My guess is that it has some problem with bus vehicles entity and it persist for each bus I add it adds same records. So if I pick two bus vehicles I will have three records

Comment: does `dump($form->getData())` looks similar to your actual `dump`?

Comment: You should remove `$busVehicles->addBusVehicleGroup($this);`. Please post the code of BusVehicle entity.

Answer (score 1):

the problem seems to be in:

```
public function addBusVehicles(BusVehicle $busVehicles)
{
    if ($this->busVehicles->contains($busVehicles)) {
        return;
    }
    $this->busVehicles->add($busVehicles);
    $busVehicles->addBusVehicleGroup($this);
}
```

when call

```
$busVehicles->addBusVehicleGroup($this);
```

your are adding a new route to the relation, try without calling this method.